# Given ODE $\dot x(t) = f(x) - x$ where $f(x)$ is bounded, we claim $x(t)$ is also bounded

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, proof-writing

**Problem:**

> Let $$\dot x(t) = f(x) - x$$
>
> Suppose that $f(x)$ is a bounded function
>
> Then we claim that the solution to the ODE $x(t)$ is bounded

**Attempt:**

Let

$$\dot x(t) = f(x) - x \implies x(t) = \int\limits_{t_o}^{t_1} f(x(t))ds - \int\limits_{t_o}^{t_1} x(t) ds $$

Then $\|x(t)\| = \|f(x(t)\||t_1-t_o| + \|x(t)||t_1-t_o| \leq K|t_1-t_o| + \|x(t)||t_1-t_o|$

$\implies \|x(t)\| \leq \dfrac{K}{1-|t_1-t_o|}, |t_1-t_o|\neq 1$

---

Is this proof valid? I feel like I have assumed that the solution will be bounded in the first place in the step "$\|x(t)\| = \|f(x(t)\||t_1-t_o| + \|x(t)||t_1-t_o|$ "

Comment: I don't think your proof is valid, as you mentioned, because you assumed that $x$ is bounded when taking $|| x ||$. But Jacky's proof works.

Comment: Assuming $t>0$?

Comment: @ZacharySelk Yes. Otherwise, we could simply take the example $\dot x = -x$ which has a solution $x(t) = e^{-t}$ where $x(t)$ blows up as $t \rightarrow -\infty$.

Comment: @JackyChong My point exactly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's another proof.

Observe
\begin{align}
\dot x + x = f(t) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{d}{dt}[xe^{tI}] = e^{tI}f(x) 
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
x(t)=e^{-(t-t_0) I}x(t_0) + \int^t_{t_0} e^{-(t-s)I} f(x(s))\ ds.
\end{align}
Thus, it follows
\begin{align}
\|x(t)\| \leq \|e^{-(t-t_0)I}x_0\| + M\int^t_{t_0} e^{-(t-s)}\ ds = \|e^{-(t-t_0)I}x_0\| + M-Me^{-(t-t_0)}\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \ \|x(t)\| \leq Ce^{-t} + M.
\end{align}

Comment: That's good but in this case $x$ could live in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Does this proof still hold?

Comment: Doesn't matter. The proof still holds.

Comment: @BeachedWhale Why don't you check that it does? Everything is on the table...

Comment: @Did Feels like there should be a matrix exponential type of thing in there some where. I will check it

Comment: $e^{It} = e^t I$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way based on a Lyapunov function.

Let $V(y) = {1 \over 2} \|y\|^2$ and $\phi(t) = V(x(t))$, 
note that
$\phi'(t) = x(t)^T (f(x(t))-x(t)) \le M \|x(t)\| - \|x(t)\|^2$.

Note that if $g(z) = Mz-z^2$, then there is some $B>0$ such that if $z \ge B$,
then $g(z) \le -1$.

Let $T= \{ t \ge 0 | \|x(t) \| \ge B+1 \}$ and
$T'= \{ t \ge 0 | \|x(t) \| \ge B \}$. Note that $\phi'(t) \le -1$ for
all $t \in T'$.

It should be clear that there is some $t^* \ge 0$ such that
$\|x(t^*)\| < B$. If not, then $\phi'(t) \le -1 $ for all $t$
which contradicts $V$ being non negative.

I claim that $T \subset [0,t^*]$.

Let $t_2 = \min \{ \tau \ge t^* | \tau \in T \}$. 
Choose $t_1 \in [t^*,t_2]$ such that $\|x(t_1)\| = B$ and
$[t_1,t_2] \subset T'$.

Then $\phi(t_2) > \phi(t_1)$ and $\phi'(t) <0$ for all $t \in [t_1,t_2]$
which contradicts the mean value theorem. Hence no such $t_2$ exists
and we have $T \subset [0,t^*]$, hence bounded.